# REST API Request for Mobile App

Tags: ios, database, api, rest, cordova

I am creating an App for iOS/Andriod using appery.io (basically a phonegap type website that uses a WYSIWYG) that will basically be a calendar for upcoming TV episodes. Users will select the shows they want to watch and the calendar/list in the App will be populated with the upcoming episodes.

For this, I am trying to use an api called thetvdb.com. However, I have only basic knowledge of databases and even less with API usage. Thetvdb has some documentation for using their API, however, it is difficult to understand and translate into the appery.io form I am using to get requests.

Using their API requires a key, which I already have. I am just not sure what to put for the settings, and request fields. The main one I need to figure out is the URL under settings first. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Settings:**
URL:
Method:
Data Type:
Content Type:

**Request:**
Not even sure what parameters to use.

**Thetvdb.com Documentation** (http://www.thetvdb.com/wiki/index.php/Programmers_API)

**The appery.io video tutorial I am following** (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_iGKRPPsRc&list=PLdUnWwhvJspZXXuozUbly21FBh9AywSa6)

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? I am completely stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You can using AFNetworking framework. It is easy to use for communication with API. 
With GET method, we can do:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil
   success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

For more information, please read on this website.
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am not sure if I understand correctly. I have a way to communicate with the API, I am just not sure how to request that information, and I would prefer to use the appery.io as opposed to another framework because I know it will work in all platforms (iOS, Android, etc).